# Check something exists in array before executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a array below that is constantly changing. It is being using in a node.js app. I have everything working good that updates elements of the array but if I restart node and the browser is still running, the webpage still sends data and causes it to crash, so I need to check if array exists before it tries to do something.

My array is like this, called users :-

```
[ { username: 'a',
    active: true,
    lat: '52.4099584',
    lng: '-1.5310848' } ]
```

So I need to check username 'a' exists. I have tried

```
users.map(obj => obj.username).indexOf(value) >= 0;
```

but doesnt work?

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `users.some( obj => obj.username === 'a' )`?

Comment: It was on here somewhere, supposed to give a true or false if exists

Comment: return users.find(user => user.username === 'a'); or as Thomas wrote. return users.some(user => user.username);

Comment: [Seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/mkt0o3pn/2/)

Comment: Wierd, that works great in jsfiddle but I get this error when added to my script result = users.map(obj => obj.username).indexOf(value) >= 0;
                                                ^

ReferenceError: value is not defined

Comment: strike that, works great and thanks for all the other advice too, really helpful and saved me loads of time and hassle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to remve the users that don't have a username, then you could do something like this.

```js
const data = [{ 
    username: 'a',
    active: true,
    lat: '52.4099584',
    lng: '-1.5310848' },
   { 
    username: undefined,
    active: true,
    lat: '52.4099584',
    lng: '-1.5310848' }];
    
    
console.log(data.filter(({username})=> username && username !== null));
```

Otherwise, you should just use something like every

```js
const data = [ { 
    username: undefined,
    active: true,
    lat: '52.4099584',
    lng: '-1.5310848' },
    { 
    username: 'a',
    active: true,
    lat: '52.4099584',
    lng: '-1.5310848' }];


console.log(data.every(({username})=> username && username !== null));
```

Or findIndex

```js
const data = [ { 
        username: undefined,
        active: true,
        lat: '52.4099584',
        lng: '-1.5310848' },
        { 
        username: 'a',
        active: true,
        lat: '52.4099584',
        lng: '-1.5310848' }];


    console.log(data.findIndex(({username})=> !username || username === null) > -1);
```